# Как изменить стиль выделенного элемента меню?

Tags: wpf, menu, style, treeview

На  изображении видно что пунк меню бело-голубой, а нужно его сделать таким же как нижний.

Так меняется стиль только меню без выделения. Но при выделении цвет бело-голубой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<TreeView Background="#FF222222"
```

Но при расфокусировании TreeView цвет фона становится белым. Как изменить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- Стиль для ListBox c типами документов -->
        <Style x:Key="SimpleListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- List Item Hover -->
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverFocusStyle" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF013B73" Offset="0.501"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF014A8F" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF003363" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <!-- List Item Selected -->
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LostFocusStyle" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF002F5C" Offset="0.4"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Style>

        <!--<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        </Style>-->

        <local:LevelToImageConverter x:Key="LevelToImageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

.

```
<MenuItem Header="Tree">
                <MenuItem Header="New Notes"  Click="NewNotes" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FF222222"
```

.

```
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Style.Resources>

                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF222222"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="Unfocused" Value="False" >
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF222222"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            </Trigger>-->

                        </Style.Triggers>


                    </Style>
```

Ничего из этого не изменило стиль

```
<Window x:Class="testmenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testmenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="25">

        <Menu.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
        </Menu.Resources>

        <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextColorKey}" Color="Green"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
        </MenuItem>




    </Menu>

</Window>
```

Comment: Суть вопроса не совсем понятно изложена, разместите пожалуйста целый код, еще лучше дополнить вопрос изображениями.

Comment: Добавте так же полный код стиля, т.к. стандартный treeview без задания стиля выглядит совсем не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подсветки активных элементов меню можно использовать следующий код:

```
<Menu x:Name="TopMainMenu">
        <Menu.Resources>              
          <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
               TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border Name="Border">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon" />                   
                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />                   
              </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
```

Нужно задать это свойство для TreeView. Оно задает цвет для необходимого вам элемента для состояния неактивности

В итоге ваш стиль должен выглядеть так

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>    
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Style.Resources>    
                          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>
                          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>   
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>                                    
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >                                    
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            </Trigger>     
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Для TreeView работает.
А для меню - неработает.
`<MenuItem.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                </MenuItem.Resources>`

Comment: Поперебирай свойства в списке слева. Должно быть подходящее https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.menuhighlightbrushkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ни одно свойство не работает

Comment: Я так понял тебе нужно подсветить MenuItem? вот тут посмотри http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790745/change-color-of-menuitem-on-mouseover